# h264 bitstream analyzer (Motion Vector)

Tags: encoding, h.264, video-processing, bitstream

From a bitstream analyzer i was able to retrieve this informations 
which is basically 3 frames first is the **I frame** and then the **P frame** and then the **B frame**

I could not figure out how to get the **Motion vector** (macroblock prediction) from the given information.

```
==================== NAL ====================
 forbidden_zero_bit : 0 
 nal_ref_idc : 3 
 nal_unit_type : 5 ( Coded slice of an IDR picture ) 
======= Slice Header =======
 first_mb_in_slice : 0 
 slice_type : 7 ( I slice only ) 
 pic_parameter_set_id : 0 
 frame_num : 0 
 field_pic_flag : 0 
 bottom_field_flag : 0 
 idr_pic_id : 0 
 pic_order_cnt_lsb : 0 
 delta_pic_order_cnt_bottom : 0 
 redundant_pic_cnt : 0 
 direct_spatial_mv_pred_flag : 0 
 num_ref_idx_active_override_flag : 0 
 num_ref_idx_l0_active_minus1 : 0 
 num_ref_idx_l1_active_minus1 : 0 
 cabac_init_idc : 0 
 slice_qp_delta : 25 
 sp_for_switch_flag : 0 
 slice_qs_delta : 0 
 disable_deblocking_filter_idc : 0 
 slice_alpha_c0_offset_div2 : 0 
 slice_beta_offset_div2 : 0 
 slice_group_change_cycle : 0 
=== Prediction Weight Table ===
 luma_log2_weight_denom : 0 
 chroma_log2_weight_denom : 0 
=== Ref Pic List Reordering ===
 ref_pic_list_reordering_flag_l0 : 0 
 ref_pic_list_reordering_flag_l1 : 0 
=== Decoded Ref Pic Marking ===
 no_output_of_prior_pics_flag : 0 
 long_term_reference_flag : 0 
 adaptive_ref_pic_marking_mode_flag : 0 
!! Found NAL at offset 2468 (0x09A4), size 539 (0x021B) 
XX 00 00 00 01 41 9A 23 6C 41 97 6D 7A 0D 74 A1 76 

==================== NAL ====================
 forbidden_zero_bit : 0 
 nal_ref_idc : 2 
 nal_unit_type : 1 ( Coded slice of a non-IDR picture ) 
======= Slice Header =======
 first_mb_in_slice : 0 
 slice_type : 5 ( P slice only ) 
 pic_parameter_set_id : 0 
 frame_num : 1 
 field_pic_flag : 0 
 bottom_field_flag : 0 
 idr_pic_id : 0 
 pic_order_cnt_lsb : 6 
 delta_pic_order_cnt_bottom : 0 
 redundant_pic_cnt : 0 
 direct_spatial_mv_pred_flag : 0 
 num_ref_idx_active_override_flag : 1 
 num_ref_idx_l0_active_minus1 : 0 
 num_ref_idx_l1_active_minus1 : 0 
 cabac_init_idc : 0 
 slice_qp_delta : 1 
 sp_for_switch_flag : 0 
 slice_qs_delta : 0 
 disable_deblocking_filter_idc : 25 
 slice_alpha_c0_offset_div2 : 0 
 slice_beta_offset_div2 : 0 
 slice_group_change_cycle : 0 
=== Prediction Weight Table ===
 luma_log2_weight_denom : 0 
 chroma_log2_weight_denom : 0
=== Ref Pic List Reordering ===
 ref_pic_list_reordering_flag_l0 : 0 
 ref_pic_list_reordering_flag_l1 : 0
=== Decoded Ref Pic Marking ===
 no_output_of_prior_pics_flag : 0 
 long_term_reference_flag : 0 
 adaptive_ref_pic_marking_mode_flag : 1 
!! Found NAL at offset 3011 (0x0BC3), size 31 (0x001F) 
XX 00 00 00 01 41 9E 42 78 83 2F 00 00 03 00 00 03 

==================== NAL ====================
 forbidden_zero_bit : 0 
 nal_ref_idc : 2 
 nal_unit_type : 1 ( Coded slice of a non-IDR picture ) 
======= Slice Header =======
 first_mb_in_slice : 0 
 slice_type : 6 ( B slice only ) 
 pic_parameter_set_id : 0 
 frame_num : 2 
 field_pic_flag : 0     
 bottom_field_flag : 0 
 idr_pic_id : 0 
 pic_order_cnt_lsb : 4 
 delta_pic_order_cnt_bottom : 0 
 redundant_pic_cnt : 0 
 direct_spatial_mv_pred_flag : 1 
 num_ref_idx_active_override_flag : 1 
 num_ref_idx_l0_active_minus1 : 0 
 num_ref_idx_l1_active_minus1 : 0 
 cabac_init_idc : 0 
 slice_qp_delta : 25 
 sp_for_switch_flag : 0 
 slice_qs_delta : 0 
 disable_deblocking_filter_idc : 0 
 slice_alpha_c0_offset_div2 : 0 
 slice_beta_offset_div2 : 0 
 slice_group_change_cycle : 0 
=== Prediction Weight Table ===
 luma_log2_weight_denom : 0 
 chroma_log2_weight_denom : 0 
=== Ref Pic List Reordering ===
 ref_pic_list_reordering_flag_l0 : 0 
 ref_pic_list_reordering_flag_l1 : 0 
=== Decoded Ref Pic Marking ===
 no_output_of_prior_pics_flag : 0 
 long_term_reference_flag : 0 
 adaptive_ref_pic_marking_mode_flag : 0 
!! Found NAL at offset 3046 (0x0BE6), size 34 (0x0022) 
XX 00 00 00 01 01 9E 61 74 41 97 00 00 03 00 00 03
```